# Create Custom Clipper UI with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I am going to create this UI using flutter, now I am confused about how to implement this custom clipper in the right up of the screen, (with arrow button inside it)

any suggestions ? 
Note : I am already tried to use `flutter_custom_clippers` package, but result is so far from what i need.

attach of the screen i Want :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) a try. its a website for designing custom clips and svgs that you can import and use in flutter.

It should allow you to design that shape and use it together in a `Stack` together with your UI.
[image]

Comment: Not working for me